# write some custom css in a wordpress column

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this code:

```
<div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_center   team_member t_icon">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper vc_box_border_circle  
         vc_box_border_grey">
           <img class="vc_single_image-img 
            "src="http://dogcentertorino.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/CL-160x160.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="CL" title="CL">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
:after
```

I am trying to assign this custom css to 
`vc_single_image-wrapper vc_box_border_circle  vc_box_border_grey`

so here the css i have written

```
 .team_member.t_icon.vc_single_image-wrapper.vc_box_border_circle 
  .vc_box_border_grey:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -18px;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background-image: url(../uploads/2018/12/iconimageafter.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

But i don't know why it seems not to read the rule at all!

Any help? 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No spaces between classes means they have to be together in the same class HTML call. You need a space after t_icon

```
     .team_member.t_icon .vc_single_image-wrapper.vc_box_border_circle 
  .vc_box_border_grey:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -18px;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background-image: url(../uploads/2018/12/iconimageafter.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Sorry my fault i was missing another custom css so everything was working fine but by forgetting in the mother class to put the overflow: visible it was not showing the image! Thank you!